# How to let Sitecore 9 RTE Link Manager use "id" attribute instead of "name" attribute for anchors

Tags: richtext-editor, link-manager

When adding an anchor link in the Link Manager inside a RTE field in Sitecore 9, the attribute `name` is used. This is no longer supported with html5 according to W3Schools:

> The  name attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use the id attribute
>   instead. The name attribute specifies the name of an anchor. The name
>   attribute is used to create a bookmark inside a document.

I need to change the behavior of the Link Manager so instead of the `name` attribute it uses the `id` attribute. The usage of the name attribute causes problems in other parts of my application.

I was not able to accomplish this. I tried using this approach (overriding the `LinkItemExpander`): [Set Data Attributes for Links to Certain Items](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6232/set-data-attributes-for-links-to-certain-items)
but I was not successful. And this approach would also not resolve the problem of anchors with an id instead of a name attribute not showing in the "Existing Anchor" DropDownList when link to them.

Can someone help me with that?